# Как первым перехватить событие в UserJS?

Tags: javascript, userjs

Как в UserJS добавить свой обработчик отправки формы так, чтобы он вызывался перед обработчиками, добавленными в скриптах самой страницы?

Answer (score 1):

А нужен ли вообще тот обработчик, который вешает сайт? Если нет, то можно просто пересоздать форму и повесить свой обработчик. Под пересозданием я имею в виду команду

```
form.outerHTML = form.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Нужен. В том-то и дело. И грузится он из замыкания.